# Super simple problem with ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I've two different classes:

**Cliente.java**

```
public class Cliente {
    private static String user;
    private static String password;
    public Cliente (String usr, String pass) {
        user = usr;
        password = pass;
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

And **AddToArrayList.java**, where I create a Client type ArrayList and and some clients:

```
public class AddToArrayList{
    static ArrayList<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Cliente c1 = new Cliente("pepe","pepe1");
        Cliente c2 = new Cliente("jose","jose1");
        Cliente c3 = new Cliente("edu","edu1");       
        listaClientes.add(c1);
        listaClientes.add(c2);
        listaClientes.add(c3);

        printArraList();
    }

    public static void printArraList() throws IOException {     
        for (Cliente c : listaClientes) {
            System.out.println(c.getUser());
        } 
    }
```

}

Why does this funciont prints me:
**edu

edu

edu**
Instead of:
**pepe

jose

edu**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "super simple problem", in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static variables are Class level variables. To have separate copies of `String user;` and `String password;` for each instance of `Cliente`, make then non-static.

Answer (score 9):

Because you've made the variable `user` in your class `Cliente` static. If you remove the `static` keyword everything should work as you want.

A `static` variable is shared across all instances of the class.

The [following site](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/instance_vs_class_members.html) has a good reference on the static keyword, I suggest you read it :).

Answer (score 2):

The following are `static`, which means that they're shared by all instances of the class:

```
private static String user;
private static String password;
```

Remove the `static` modifiers, and each instance will get its own `user` and `password`.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared the fields in `Cliente` static. So the fields keep the last value that you've set: and thats user `edu`.

Change it to:

```
private String user;
private String password;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the static modifier, as it is used if there is a need for a variable to be common to all the objects of a single java class. An instance is not a must to modify the static variable, which is not required in case of user and password in your case.